Can i enable WPA3 security by programatically in android p2p?
I have an application capable of creating a wifi direct group with a custom group SSID and password, but it works with normal WPA2.
How to enable WPA3 security with P2P group in Android programmatically, is it possible? Are there other possibilities available?
Could you please help
Thanks in advance.
I have checked the official website but I'm not getting any sample or guidance.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager

According to the API documentation there is only WPA2 support:

Wi-Fi Direct supports WPA2 encryption. (Some ad-hoc networks support only WEP encryption.)

https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/wifi/wifi-direct

Thanks, and I have noticed some documents related to WPA3 in android 12 above, at
https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-wpa3-owe
is this use full to me? should i root my device for this?
how to achieve this? could you please help me..

@Francis_M The important sentence on the linked page is WPA3 and Wi-Fi Enhanced Open are supported only in client mode. which means it has no effect on the AccessPoint (AP) mode.

Thanks, it's very much useful. @Robert
